# Get Selected String from the ListView

Tags: android

I have ListView in my project which has ListItems as in the form of String like this,

Complete Task By Today
Assign Projects To Developers
Meeting Cancelled

if click any one of the item from  ListView means i want that particular String should be displayed in my EditText(i,e if click meeting cancelled, i need this particular String to display in EditText).Any one guide me,This is how i'm trying to Achieve.enter code here Thanks in advance.

final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.taskListDesc);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int selectedItem,
                long arg3) {

            System.out.println(adapter.getItemAtPosition(selectedItem));

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ViewTaskActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: try to use String `listItemSelected_TextValue = ((TextView) view).getText();` if using `TextView`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, profielNames); 
setListAdapter(adapter);

 @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

  // Get the data associated with selected item
  Object item = l.getItemAtPosition(position);
  String myitem = item.toString();
  edittxt.setText("Selected item is :"+ myitem); // You can Set EditText from Here.
 }
```

Comment: If you have writtend extends listview then above code is relevent, else onitemClick() will work.

Comment: Ya i tried your code Dev i selected one listitem from list view i'm getting that selected listValue i mean i'm  not getting that particular string rather i'm getting like this TasksList@44ef4bc8

Comment: Have you used (extends ListActivity)

Comment: No i just extended only Activity

Comment: Then just change it to ListActivity

Comment: i could convert to listAcitivity because i have onCreate method in my class.

Comment: No problem Buddy, onCreate method is in ListActivity also, Have a look at this example => http://www.learn-android.com/2009/12/05/lots-of-lists-1-simple/

Comment: yeah it was much helpful for me and its working fine thank you dev.

Answer (score 2):

You can even try this.....

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

String str_arr[] = {"A", "B", "C"};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, str_arr));

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Object o = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String str_text = o.toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(ExampleActivity.this, NewExample.class);
            intent.putExtra("StrValue", str_text);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
 }
 }
```

---

```
public class NewExample extends Activity {

EditText editText;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newmain);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("StrValue").toString();

    editText.setText(value);
}

}
```

Hope this helps.......

Njoy coding.....